# extj4 grid doesn't fit in container panel

Tags: layout, extjs, grid, extjs4

I have a grid with data, contained in a panel which also hold a title and a smaller summary grid. 
the panel has layout fit and therefore the title and first grid, which is the summary grid, are displayed just fine. But the grid in question has more records than can be shown on the screen and its component height is not adjusted to the size of the panel which always fits with the height of the browser window.

What I would like to have is that the grid component's height, like the panel, is adjusted to its parent so that the scrollbar inside the grid body will show up.

My code is similar to this (initComponent is of an extension to Ext.panel.Panel):
(header in this code means the summary grid)

```
initComponent: function (config) {
    var config = {
        border: false,
        hidden: false,
        hideMode: "display",
        padding: '5',
        layout: "fit"
    }

    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
    this.callParent(arguments);

    title = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        html: '<h2>title</h2>',
        padding: '5',
        border: false
    });

// the stores for the grids are created here
    var storeHdr = DataStoreFactory.CreateStore("GetHeaderP", DataStoreFactory.fieldsCollection.Default);
    var storeBdy = DataStoreFactory.CreateStore("GetBodyP", DataStoreFactory.fieldsCollection.Default);

    var grdHeader = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
        store: storeHdr,
        columns: getHeaderColumns(), 
        columnLines: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        enableHdMenu: false,
        enableColumnMove: false,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        disableSelection: true,
        trackMouseOver: false,
        sortable: false
    });

    var grdBody = Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
        id: id,
        store: storeBdy,
        columns: getBodyColumns(), 
        columnLines: true,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        scroll: "vertical",
        enableColumnMove: false,
        enableColumnResize: false,
        enableHdMenu: false,
        trackMouseOver: false,
        disableSelection: true
    });
},

    var headerGridContainer = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        layout: "fit",
        border: false,
        items: [grdHeader]
    });
    var bodyGridContainer = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
        layout: "fit",
        border: false,
        items: [grdBody]
    });

    this.add(title);
    this.add(headerGridContainer);
    this.add(bodyGridContainer);
    storeHdr.load();
    storeBdy.load();
    this.doLayout();
}
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance

edit - screenshots how it is and how it should be. Realtime Data is removed or blotted out, since it is private and doesn't matter for the problem.

[image: how it is]
this is how it is

[image: how it should be]
this is how it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using layouts in a wrong way. First, your main container has layout 'fit' which supposed to be used when you have single item inside - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Fit - and you have few items.

Second, try to avoid over-nesting. You're wrapping your grids into panels and then put these panels inside container. Is there a reason for that?

Please post a screenshot of what you have and what you want to have and we will help you figure out layouts that you need to use for this.

**Update:**

Try to use `layout: 'hbox'` in your main container. And specify `flex: 1` for the main (bottom) grid if you want it to fill the rest of the screen. Son basically you would have something simliar to this (in you main container):

```
{
   layout: 'hbox',
   ..
   items: [{
      xtype: 'panel', // header
      height: 100, 
   },
   {
      xtype: 'grid', // first grid
      height: 200
   },
   {
      xtype: 'grid', // second grid
      flex: 1
   }]
}
```

Comment: I added the screenshots. I hope it is clear enough. On the first picture the grid border lines go all the way beyond the bottom border of the panel, while in the second (how it should be) the grid panel bottom border ends about five pixels above the bottom border of the outer panel.

Comment: didn't you mean vbox instead of hbox? anyway no mather which layout I choose, I keep having the same problem ... :( (I did remove the wrapper panels btw)

Comment: I got this working without setting the layout for the panel that holds the title and the two grids and calculating the height for the second grid.